# can i compare 2 SDL_Surface (whether they are the same or not)

Tags: c, sdl-2

While making a game with SDL2 in c,i have to compare 2 SDL_Surface to check a win condition but i couldn't find a way to do so

Comment: Are you sure there's not a better way to do it? It sounds like an XY problem. You can compare them by comparing the color of each pixel but it looks like you shouldn't ever find yourself doing it.

Comment: thank you for your answer,i am basically making a sudoku with shapes that i made using SDL_Surface and  i need to check if the sudoku is correct

Comment: so I guess you should have a data structure which contains the logic status of your sudoku, that's what you want to compare, not the graphical output

Comment: i used a 2d array of SDL_Surface and i have to compare its elements

Comment: @hamzabouqdir Make another 2d array of integer to store the numbers contained in each slot.

Comment: @okovko thanks for your proposition ,but how can i use this 2d array of integer to match the 2d array of SDL_Surface given by the user

Comment: Determine which digit a given surface represents. You only have 9 surfaces to check for 9 digits. Just find a set of pixels locations such that they are unique for any given surface 0-9.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're interested in comparing two `SDL_Surfaces`, so here is how you do it. There is probably a better way to solve your specific problem, but anyways:

From the [SDL Wiki](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Surface), `SDL_Surface` has members of interest `format, w, h, pitch, pixels`.

- `format` represents the pixel encoding information

  - `format->format` is the specific enumeration constant specifying a  given encoding
- `w` represents the number of pixels in a row of pixels in the surface
- `h` represents the number of rows of pixels in the surface
- `pitch` represents the byte length of a row
- `pixels` is an array with all the pixel data

If you want to compare two `SDL_Surfaces`, you need to compare the pixels against one another. But first we should check that the pixel encoding and the dimensions match:

```
int SDL_Surfaces_comparable(SDL_Surface *s1, SDL_Surface *s2) {
  return (s1->format.format == s2->format.format && s1->w == s2->w && s1->h == s2->h);
}
```

If `SDL_Surfaces_comparable` evaluates to `true`, we can check if two surfaces are equal by comparing the `pixels` fields byte by byte.

```
int SDL_Surfaces_equal(SDL_Surface *s1, SDL_Surface *s2) {
  if (!SDL_Surfaces_comparable(s1, s2)) {
    return 0;
  }
  // the # of bytes we want to check is bytes_per_row * rows
  int len = s1->pitch * s1->h;
  return memcmp(s1->pixels, s2->pixels, len);
}
```

This assumes that pixel data is serialized as bytes without any padding, or that the padding is zeroed. I couldn't find any `SDLPixel` structure, so I'm assuming this is the standard way to compare pixels. I did find this [link](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/Pixel_Access), which seems to verify my approach.

Comment: This has a bug: the number of bytes to be checked (len) is **not** `s1->format->BytesPerPixel * s1->pitch * s1->h`, but `s1->pitch * s1->h`. In [SDL_Surface's wiki page](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_Surface), there's even a code sample that states: "height times pitch is the size of the surface's whole buffer".

Actually, two bugs: you check `i` at the end, but you declared it in the for loop, which means it's out of scope. You have to declare it before the loop.